# System.setClipboard in event initiated by user click

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm new to flash so my question may be stupid.

I unserstand security restrictions about working with clipboard. The user must do an action then clipboard may be written.

But what if on mouseclick i have to load some text from server using URLRequest and copy obtained data to clipboard?

Like this:

```
    protected function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
       this.fileReference = new FileReference();
       this.fileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, this.fileSelectHandler);       
       this.fileReference.browse();
    }       

    protected function fileSelectHandler(e:Event):void
    {
       var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(this.url);
       this.urlLoader = new URLLoader();
       urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.completeHandler);
       urlLoader.load(request);
    }

    protected function generateLinkCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
    {
       System.setClipboard(this.urlloader.data);            

}
```

Maybe somehow it is possible to "pass" the "safe context" to further events? 
or it's another way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: A similar question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427543/system-setclipboard-inside-event-handler  The short answer is no. If you find a method to do it, Adobe will treat it as a security flaw, and patch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sydd who answered my question in comments. I'll copy the link provided by him here [System.setClipboard() inside event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427543/system-setclipboard-inside-event-handler)
if he consider to write it as an answer i'll reaccept.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with two clicks: one to fetch the data and when that's loaded, show a button that will copy to clipboard when clicked?

Comment: Because one click is mostly allways better than two =)